# Creating Parametrized Jenkins Project via XML API

Tags: xml, rest, jenkins

This is the xml I am posting to my jenkins server. I am trying to create a parameterized Jenkins project via the xml api.  I am posting to http://localhost:8080/createItem?name=testjob. It is creating the job, but there are no build parameter definitions. This needs to be a parameterized project that accepts a single CALLBACK_URL parameter for each build.

Am I missing something? How do I create a parameterized build via the api? Where is the information documented? I am having a great amount of difficulty finding where this might be documented

```
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description/>
  <keepDependencies>true</keepDependencies>
  <properties/>
  <scm class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers class="vector"/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders>
    <hudson.tasks.Shell>
      <command>test</command>
    </hudson.tasks.Shell>
  </builders>
  <publishers/>
  <buildWrappers/>
  <action>
    <parameterDefinition>
      <defaultParameterValue>
        <value>google.com</value>
      </defaultParameterValue>
      <description>webhook callback</description>
      <type>StringParameterDefinition</type>
      <name>CALLBACK_URL</name>
    </parameterDefinition>
  </action>
  <property>
    <parameterDefinition>
      <defaultParameterValue>
        <value>google.com</value>
        <name>CALLBACK_URL</name>
      </defaultParameterValue>
      <description>webhook callback</description>
      <type>StringParameterDefinition</type>
      <name>CALLBACK_URL</name>
    </parameterDefinition>
  </property>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was posting the wrong XML.  I looked at the xml config for projects i created through the jenkins GUI. The following xml, when posted does what I wanted to do, namely creating a parameterized jenkins project

```
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description/>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties>
    <hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
      <parameterDefinitions>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
          <name>CALLBACK_URL</name>
          <description>webhook callback url</description>
          <defaultValue/>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
        <hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
          <name>TYPE</name>
          <description>build type</description>
          <defaultValue>ALL</defaultValue>
        </hudson.model.StringParameterDefinition>
      </parameterDefinitions>
    </hudson.model.ParametersDefinitionProperty>
  </properties>
  <scm type="scm" class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders>
    <hudson.tasks.shell>
      <command>test</command>
    </hudson.tasks.shell>
  </builders>
  <publishers/>
  <buildWrappers/>
</project>
```